# SQL for Time Blocks (10 Day intervals from Varying Start Dates)

Tags: sql, intervals, group

I have a table with IDs and Dates. The first date should act as a START timer for a ten day block where any records falling within the next ten days should not be counted as a new incident. The first record outside of that initial ten day block should be counted as a new instance and serve as a START timer for a new 10 day block.

Any ideas on how I can structure a query to get an output similar to this?

| ID | Date | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 8/22/23 | 1 * |
| 123456 | 8/23/23 | 0 |
| 123456 | 8/29/23 | 0 |
| 123456 | 9/04/23 | 1 * |
| 123456 | 9/08/23 | 0 |
| 123456 | 9/16/23 | 1 * |

*Starting points for time blocks are not fixed and dependent on previous sequence of events:

1. START 8/22/23 (END 9/01/23)
2. START 9/04/23 (END 9/14/23)
3. START 9/16/23 (END 9/26/23)

I haven't had to deal with sliding time windows before so this is a new frustration, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Search for "SQL gaps and islands" and see if any of the results are helpful.

Comment: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70611380/detect-consecutive-dates-in-sql-and-start-counter

Comment: I don't believe this problem is gaps and island. I wish I had a proof handy for you but the solution is that you must run through the dates in sequence by loop or cursor and then mark each off one by one as to whether it falls within the current window or starts a new one.

Comment: Are the blocks always 10? What is the _Varying_ component, also there is no sliding time window here, that is a very different outcome. Important to get these terms right of you will attract misleading answers

Comment: The Ids in your output are also misleading. You should provide an example of the raw data input as well as the expected output to match that data. Order is significant here too, _"first"_ is ambiguous, what is the sort ordering? We might assume the Date column, but in SQL we should be explicit

Comment: @Chris, by "varying" it means that the anchors for each window are not fixed to a set schedule. The starting points will vary based on the sequence of dates that came before it.

Comment: Normally yes, but in this example that is not clear. You should include the raw dataset, because I can't see how those values match a rolling 10 day window at all

Comment: For instance, on the 4th the Count is 1, on the 8th the count is zero, but the 16th the count is 1... That zero record is within 10 of both 4th and 16th, so without the raw dataset it looks wrong

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I apologize for the ambiguity- shawnt00's interpretation is correct and yes, always 10 day blocks.  Sorted by ID, Date ASC, the "first" Date, will serve as a START for any following Dates falling in the 10 day block.  In my example, The first block begins 8/22, since it is the first record for that ID, should return Count 1. Any occurrences within 10 days of that date would return Count 0.  9/4 is the first instance beyond 10 days from 8/22 and serves as a new START, returning Count 1.  Same applies to 9/16, this returns Count 1 based on the previous START date of 9/4.

Comment: So you should put this information in the post. What was not clear to me is the relationship with `ID`. So your example really should include multiple IDs. Right now it just looks like an obvious mistake, why would a table that has ID and Date only have duplicate IDs at all. It looks like you have over simplified this example

Comment: this is a simple gap and island, what RDBMS?

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of iterative or recursive solution for this problem. A row by row cursor is one straightforward approach. Here is some looping pseudo-code that is a bit more set-based:

```
while exists (select 1 from T where "count" is null) -- assumes that null means unmarked
begin
    update T
    set "count" = -1 -- temporarily mark the new windows as -1
    where "count" is null and not exists (
        select 1 from T t2
        where   t2.id = T.id and t2."count" is null
            and t2."date" between T."date" - 9 days and T."date" - 1 day
    );
    update T
    set "count" = case "count" when -1 then 1 else 0 end
    where "count" = -1 or "count" is null and exists (
        select 1 from T t2
        where t2.id = T.id and t2."count" = -1
            and t2."date" between T."date" - 9 days and T."date" - 1 day
    );        
end
```

A recursive solution should work but the limits on depth of recursion could come into play when there are long streaks unbroken by a gap of ten days or more:

```
with data as (
    select *,
        lag(dt, 1, '20000101') over (partition by id order by dt) as last_dt from T
), blocks as (
    select id, dt, 1 as cnt
    from data
    where datediff(day, last_dt, dt) > 9
    union all
    select d.id, d.dt,
        case when datediff(day, b.dt, d.dt) < 9 then 0 else 1 end as cnt
    from blocks b inner join data d on d.id = b.id and b.cnt = 1
        and datediff(day, b.dt, d.last_dt) between 0 and 9 -- lagged to get next link
        and datediff(day, d.last_dt, d.dt) <= 9  
)
select * from blocks
option (maxrecursion 100);
```

Each chain begins where are large gaps with the prior row. After that the chain must be followed down each set of rows to determine where they fall relative to the top of the chain. So the recursion depth needed is going to be roughly the total length in days from top to bottom divided by 10.

https://dbfiddle.uk/ZDjPc4Yx

Comment: Thank you so much for putting the time into this answer! Just wondering how you were able to call on 'blocks' within blocks in the second set of code?

Comment: @mstan You'll want to look into how recursive queries work. Essentially there are multiple passes as it descends through the data. It's like starting at the top of a family tree. First you look for the children. On the next pass it find the children of the children and so on.

Comment: I see! It appears that Impala does not support recursive queries in the WITH so I will have to figure out a workaround.

Comment: @mstan I think your only workaround is some kind of manual loop as I did at the top of the answer. The alternative is to chain multiple CTEs. Do you have any idea what the average days between events is?

Answer (score 0):

You need a dataset to represent the *time blocks*, in this case a fixed block of 10 days. You can generate this using a recursive CTE or for performance reasons you might already have a [tally table](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/tally-tables-in-t-sql#Tally%20Tables%20in%20SQL%202008), or another table with lots of rows that we can use to seed our *time blocks*.

This is a simple SQL Server example of using recursion for this that will build 10 day intervals from the *minimum* date in a source table called `DataTable`

```
WITH Dates
AS (
  SELECT [FromDate] = MIN([Date]), [ToDate] = DATEADD(DAY,10,MIN([Date])), [StopDate] = MAX([Date]) FROM DataTable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT [FromDate] = previousRow.[ToDate], [ToDate] = DATEADD(DAY,10, previousRow.[ToDate]), previousRow.StopDate
  FROM Dates as previousRow
  WHERE previousRow.ToDate < [StopDate]
)
-- Output the Date Blocks
SELECT [FromDate], [ToDate] FROM Dates;
```

We can then join the result set from this CTE back against the original set and group the rows by these date blocks

```
WITH Dates
AS (
  SELECT [FromDate] = MIN([Date]), [ToDate] = DATEADD(DAY,10,MIN([Date])), [StopDate] = MAX([Date]) FROM DataTable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT [FromDate] = previousRow.[ToDate], [ToDate] = DATEADD(DAY,10, previousRow.[ToDate]), previousRow.StopDate
  FROM Dates as previousRow
  WHERE previousRow.ToDate < [StopDate]
)
SELECT Dates.FromDate as [Date], COUNT(DataTable.[Date]) AS [Count] 
FROM Dates
LEFT OUTER JOIN DataTable ON Dates.[FromDate] <= DataTable.[Date] AND Dates.[ToDate] > DataTable.[Date]
GROUP BY Dates.[FromDate]
```

> **NOTE:** Because the values are DATE and not DATETIME this solution does NOT use `BETWEEN`. `BETWEEN` is *inclusive* of both limits so using it in this logic would count some rows is multiple blocks.

See this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/I6yb3usQ
*Raw data is randominsed, so you will get different results in that fiddle*

| Date | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-08-22 | 2 |
| 2023-09-01 | 0 |
| 2023-09-11 | 3 |
| 2023-09-21 | 3 |
| 2023-10-01 | 0 |
| 2023-10-11 | 0 |
| 2023-10-21 | 3 |
| 2023-10-31 | 0 |
| 2023-11-10 | 2 |
| 2023-11-20 | 1 |
| 2023-11-30 | 0 |
| 2023-12-10 | 1 |
| 2023-12-20 | 2 |
| 2023-12-30 | 0 |
| 2024-01-09 | 1 |
| 2024-01-19 | 1 |
| 2024-01-29 | 2 |
| 2024-02-08 | 0 |
| 2024-02-18 | 1 |
| 2024-02-28 | 1 |

> `ID` has been deliberately excluded from this output as it doesn't normally make sense to include it, especially for the dates with no instances, where would we source the ID for that block? Though possible to resolve, doing so is out of scope for this post without a lot more information.